# Need help for my first steps with React-Redux

Tags: redux

I am struggeling on getting my first steps with Redux. All of these "Todo-App" Tutorials are nice, the "Increment the button" tutorials as well. I thought of getting my own example to teach myself the logic of Redux, but something doesnt work. At the moment, I am not sure where the state comes from, so I tried a lot of different variations to have Redux "started" without getting initialization errors, and I found a working solution! First, I just setted up the state in the reducer, but the button-describtion didnt appear. Then, I setted up the state in the store additionally, and at least the button has the decribtion test123 and the console.log worked. But how to get the state from the reducer (I checked the documentation and it was recommended to pass state by reducers, not by the store itself). At the moment, I get the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here is my absolutely basic code which should help me understand the logic of redux:

Action type:

```
export const CLICK = 'CLICK'
```

Action Creator:

```
import { CLICK } from './types';

export function clicked() {
    return({
        type: CLICK,
        payload: 'switch the describtion of the button'
    })
}
```

the clickReducer:

```
import { CLICK } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    name: 'test'
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    console.log('click-test', action)
    switch(action.type) {
        case CLICK: {
            return Object.assign({}, state)
        }
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

the rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import clickReducer from './clickReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    name: clickReducer
})
```

the store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {
    name: 'test123' 
};

const middleWare = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleWare));

export default store;
```

and the button-component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { clicked } from '../actions/clickAction';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.clicked}>{this.props.name}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    name: state.name
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { clicked })(Button);
```

It would be very nice to get some help with this issue to be able to take further steps in Redux. 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm kinda lost with what you're trying to achieve. You can get your store state via `mapStateToProps` and it seem like you set it up correctly. The only problem I have with your code is that your `clickReducer` seems to be not updating your store (or maybe it is different from the method I use) and your `clicked` action should not be called in `onClick` that way. Can you specify what your problem really is? Is it like, I clicked the button and the state wont update?

Comment: the onClick works by this way, but the state does not change so the button still remains described "name" instead of test. :(((((

Answer (score 2):

You don't need parentheses, do this instead:

```
import { CLICK } from './types';

export clicked = () => {
    return {
        type: CLICK,
        payload: 'switch the describtion of the button'
    }
}
```

Your "CLICK" type in the switch statement isn't updating the name, you're just returning the state. Do this, instead:

```
import { CLICK } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    name: 'test'
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case CLICK: 
            return {
              ...state,
              name: action.payload
         }    
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Your store has too much information, do this instead:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store;
```

Call the object property:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { clicked } from '../actions/clickAction';

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.clicked}>{this.props.name.name}</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    name: state.name
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { clicked })(Button);
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution, regarding the reducer, still leads to the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {0, 1, 2, 3}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in button (at button.js:9)
    in div (at button.js:8)
    in Button (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at App.js:12)
    in div (at App.js:11)
    in Provider (at App.js:10)
    in App (at src/index.js:6) react-dom.development.js:57
    React 15
    dispatchInteractiveEvent self-hosted:1029
```

I really cant imagine why it is like this, because my solution looks like okay and this is a very very primitive app to change the button description :(((

Comment: Thorsten, on Button.js file try this:  { this.props.name.name }.